# JPA - generated query for persist method does not insert all columns

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-6, websphere-8, openjpa

I'm fairly new to JPA and I am having a problem with the entity manager persist method for one particular entity. I have a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
  Id                INTEGER                     NOT NULL,
  GroupId           INTEGER                     NOT NULL,
  ItemId            INTEGER                     NOT NULL,
  Expires           NUMBER(9,2)
)
```

The entity class looks similar to this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Items")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "item_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "item_seq", sequenceName = "ITEM_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "GroupId")
    private int groupId;

    @Column(name = "ItemId")
    private int itemId;

    @Column(name = "Expires")
    private int expires;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }
    public void setGroupId(int groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }
    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }
    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }
    public int getExpires() {
        return expires;
    }
    public void setExpires(int expires) {
        this.expires = expires;
    }
}
```

In the repository class I have the following:

```
@Inject
private UserTransaction userTransaction;
...
userTransaction.begin()
Item item = new Item();
item.setItemId(itemId);
item.setGroupId(groupId);
em.persist(item);
userTransaction.commit()
```

I get the following exception when it attempts to commit:

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("schema-name"."Items"."GroupId")

The issue is that JPA is generating the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Items (Id, ItemId) VALUES (?, ?)
```

I can't figure out why JPA is skipping the GroupId column. I've confirmed that the groupId has a valid value, and I've also tried adding *insertable = true* to the Column attribute. As I mentioned, it's the only entity where I'm seeing this issue. I've searched around but have found no similar problems. I'm on Java EE 6, WebSphere, and OpenJPA 2.2.3.

Comment: Did you try writing a constuctor in Item class for itemId and groupId?

Comment: Another good possibility is that groupId is somehow a keyword for OpenJpa or oracle or something. Try changing the name just to see if it works better.

Comment: @K.Nicholas the actual column name is GROUP_ID. That just so happens to be a function name in Oracle. I had no idea (I'm new to Oracle). I realized it when I was writing a stored procedure as a workaround to this problem and I saw that GROUP_ID was identified as a keyword. I tried escaping the column name with double quotes in the entity class, but that did not work. Unfortunately I can't change the column name in the database, so it looks like I'll have to stick with a native query or stored procedure.

Comment: You might also try putting the full set of parameters in the `@Table` annotation. I think it takes schema and other parameters that might help differentiate between the column and the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most probably because you have mixed cases in your name declarations and actual table names. For me Oracle (some 11.2 if i remember right...) always creates all table- & column names UPPERCASE. Your create script might actually equal to:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEMS (
    ID        INTEGER    NOT NULL,
    GROUPID   INTEGER    NOT NULL,
    ITEMID    INTEGER    NOT NULL,
    EXPIRES   NUMBER(9,2)
)
```

You can force your own case by wrapping names with `"` when creating tables so for example:

```
CREATE TABLE "Items" ... -- and all the rest columns
```

So actually you are able to have for example  tables `Items` & `ITEMS` at the same time. *(I actually have had the same issue also with Postgres which defaults all names to lowercase)*.

**Anyway**: check first the case your fields actually are in the database.

If your table really has column names like `GroupId` then you can try to 'escape' the name in annotation with `"`, like:

```
@Column(name = "\"GroupId\"")
```

If they are default UPPERCASE try accordingly:

```
@Column(name = "GROUPID")
```

**Note**: that this should be applied to all of your differently cased fields.

Peculiar detail is that - at least for me and seems also to be the case with you & Oracle - that JPA however seems to find the table no matter the case of the name but then finding the columns fail.

Most of the time the best practice is to keep things default if there is not some very stroing reason to make deviations. So whenever worked with Oracle we have used the UPPERCASE everywhere.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the actual column name is GROUP_ID, which is a function name in Oracle. I tried escaping the column name in the entity class as you show in your post, but I was still getting the same error. This may be a bug or limitation in the OpenJPA version I'm using, but I haven't had a chance to look further into it. I think I will have to settle for a workaround.